# Shell script to zcat and gunzip multiple files

Tags: shell-script, awk, gunzip

I have the following files

```
SiteTraffic_1141875176444311430_20191120.json.gz0000.gz
SiteTraffic_1141875176444311430_20191120.json.gz0001.gz
SiteTraffic_1141875176444311430_20191120.json.gz0002.gz

SiteTraffic_1142999846441591053_20191120.json.gz0001.gz    
SiteTraffic_1142999846441591053_20191120.json.gz0000.gz
SiteTraffic_1142999846441591053_20191120.json.gz0002.gz
```

I need to make a script to zcat these split files by site number then gunzip them.

I tried running them through a loop and comparing the site numbers but this is as far as I could get

```
#!/bin/bash

site1=""
FL=""
for f in ls-l *20191120*;
        do site2=`echo $f| awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[2]}'`;
        if [ "$site1" == "$site2" ]; then
                FL= echo $FL " " $f
        else
                site1="$site2"
                FL=""
        fi
        echo "FL" $FL
done
```

Comment: Could you say something more about what "zcat these split files by site number then gunzip them" means? Do you want to concatenate some of the files based on some part of their filenames? What part is the "site number"?

Comment: "_to `zcat` these split files by site number then `gunzip` them_" doesn't really make sense. The `zcat` command will uncompress the file contents to its _stdout_, so there is surely no need to `gunzip` them because the content has already been decompressed on the fly.